# Logistic regression on a dataset with text features

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, feature-engineering

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
category 1  category 2  prediction

    X   a   1
    Y   b   0
    Z   b   1
    X   a   1
    Y   a   0
    Z   b   0
    X   b   1
    Y   f   1
    Z   d   1
```

Let us say these are the three columns. I want to mention that column 1 & 2 are text features and not numeric data. My input data will contain 15-20 different types in `category 1`. Each of this type in `category 1` can have a type in `category 2`. Eg. `X` can have entries of type `a` twice or thrice & entries of type `b` twice. The third column is the output. I want to train a model on such a dataset and finally after the model is trained, I want to pass any one `category 1` & `category 2`, Eg: `X` & `a` - this should give me a predicted output of `1` or `0`. I am intending to use a logistic regression for this purpose.

Question:

1. Since I have text data, should I use dummies and create a column for each type? (eg. since I have `X`, `Y`, `Z` should I create three different columns and assign a `1` or a `0`.
2. Can I use logistic regression for this or does it not suit my application? (I would prefer getting probability of predicting `1`)

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: "text data" implies data like emails - I think you mean that you have "categorical data". As long as your categorical data is of the class `factor`, most R model function will create the dummy variables for you.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I mean just words, eg say these are names of sports, Baseball, Volleyball, Ice-hockey etc. Do you mean to say such columns with words can be passed as features in logistic regression?

Answer (score 3):

[Logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) fits if your classification is based on the log-odds of being in each category.  For a binary classification, it doesn't differ much in results from comparable methods.

Yes, you should use your "dummies" for the categorical data.  This is called "one-hot encoding", from an electrical design technique in which, at any given time, exactly one wire of a cluster would be "hot" (have current).  For your posted data, you would have three columns for category 1, and at least four columns (a, b, d, f) for category 2.

Comment: Yes, and if you use the built-in `glm` method in R for logistic regression, the dummy encoding will be automatic as long as your data is `factor`